# Korean currency symbol converting to "?" while writing to CSV file using Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, export-to-csv, charset

I am exporting a table into CSV using Java code. The code can have price in any currency.
Following code is used to do that

If Currency is GBP is Euro

```
StreamUtils.copy(writer.toString(), Charset.forName("Cp1252"), response.getOutputStream());
```

If any other currency

```
  

 StreamUtils.copy(writer.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8, response.getOutputStream());
```

This is done to correctly display the currency symbol. First line works fine for Euro and GBP but shows ? for Korean and few other symbols, though during debugging it correctly captures the korean currency symbol. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get it. For one thing I don't know what `StreamUtils` is. But why would you change a character set to get a currency symbol? You do know that UTF-8 has all currency symbols? Needless to say, you can't do Korean with Cp1252

Comment: As far as I'm aware `₩` is not in cp1252. Unless I'm misreading, why not run it through the utf8 encoding?

Comment: Where and how are you displaying your currency symbol? In a console? When opening the CSV file in a text file reader? What font is used (and does it support the symbol)? What encoding is assumed by the console/tool? Why not use UTF-8 end-to-end for all your data?

Comment: Open the file up using a program like `Notepad++`. It can do a good job of guessing the character encoding of the file. My guess is that it's `UTF8`. It might be a good idea to encode your output file to `UTF8` also.

Comment: "dont know why it was downvoted" --> What is "response" in "response.getOutputStream()"? Where does "writer.toString()" come from? Your own class? What is "StreamUtils.copy"? You left so much open to interpretation and guess work. There was also no "working code" that anyone could use to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be switching between Windows 1252 and UTF-8, which seems like a strange decision, why not just always deliver UTF-8?

So, if you want to support 2 different encodings, you have to:

1. Set the 2 options in "produces"
2. Set the type with the character set:

e.g.

```
...
.header("content-type","text/plain;charset=Cp1252")
...
```

or

```
... 
.header("content-type","text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
...
```

Original answer showed both possible options :

```
. . . 
// .header("content-type","text/plain;charset=[Cp1252|UTF-8]")
. . .
```

Comment: Interesting, but how would a CSV viewer be able to read two different encodings simultaneously?

Comment: `charset=[Cp1252|UTF-8]` - I have never seen that syntax before. Is there any documentation describing what it means, precisely, and how it works? I have not been able to find anything, except for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#charset). And the term is `charset` singular, not `charsets` plural - but not sure how much I can read into that...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought that it was clear that a regexp "xor" was implied. I have updated my answer to hopefully make it clear.

Comment: That's an OR, but of what kind, I've no idea. Still mystified

Comment: @g00se: OP uses `Charset.forName("Cp1252")` and/or `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, so this has to be added to the response, depending on what encoding is used. Otherwise the client receiving the data genuinely has not idea what it is getting in the respnse.

Comment: Ah OK. So that OR was pseudocode then, I think you mean. I thought this was some kind of *actual* esoteric code and I don't think I was the only one that thought that ;)